# Phonegap on iphone application with SenchaTouch

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am new in phonegap development environment and i want to use Sencha touch for building of my iphone application.Please anybody guide me how  will i use sencha touch for building of  my iphone app?
I wants steps, how will i use sencha touch  with xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James Pearce of Sencha put together a comprehensive tutorial on building an iPhone app with PhoneGap, Sencha Touch, and xcode [here](http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap).

Comment: Could , you pls suggest what image size is require for setting the background ground image for all mobile apps?

Comment: I'm not sure one size makes sense for all, but perhaps you should ask another stackoverflow question.